# EF6 Linq to Sql column alias exceeds 30 characters

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I am converting our Data Access Layer from Telerik ORM (deprecated) to EF 6. It connects to an Oracle 12c datasource with a 30 character limit. Some table names and column names are exactly 30 characters (as in this example below), some are shorter.

The Linq to Sql queries already exist and worked find with Telerik because it used alias for column names as t1, t2, etc.. whereas EF apparently copies the original column name as the alias. In most cases this works except for code table joins where both the PK of the code table and the FK of the parent table are exactly the same, then it appends a 1 to the end of the column alais thus making it 31 characters. As you can guess Oracle complains.

I need to find a way to force EF to use a shorter alias, any way to do this?

Here is the Linq query:

```
var dbElevationsHistory = (from elevationHist in dbContext.ElevationDataReadingJournals
join it in dbContext.MeasurementIssueTypes on elevationHist.MeasurementIssueTypeId equals it.MeasurementIssueTypeId into iType
from issueType in iType.DefaultIfEmpty()
join mt in dbContext.ElevationMeasureMethodTypes on elevationHist.ElevationMeasureMethodTypeId equals mt.ElevationMeasureMethodTypeId into mType
from methodType in mType.DefaultIfEmpty()
join at in dbContext.ElevationAccuracyTypes on elevationHist.ElevationAccuracyTypeId equals at.ElevationAccuracyTypeId into aType
from accuracyType in aType.DefaultIfEmpty()
join cAgency in dbContext.Organizations on elevationHist.CoopAgencyOrganizationId equals cAgency.OrganizationId into foundAgencies
from coopAgency in foundAgencies.DefaultIfEmpty()
where elevationHist.StationId == wellKey
select new { elevationHist, issueType, accuracyType, methodType, coopAgency })
   .OrderByDescending(eh => eh.elevationHist.ModifiedDate)
   .OrderByDescending(eh => eh.elevationHist.ElevationDataReadingJournalId);
```

And the sql query it produces:

```
SELECT 
"Project1"."C1" AS "C1", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READ_JRL_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READ_JRL_ID", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READING_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READING_ID", 
"Project1"."CRUD_TYPE" AS "CRUD_TYPE", 
"Project1"."CRUD_DT" AS "CRUD_DT", 
"Project1"."MEASUREMENT_DT" AS "MEASUREMENT_DT", 
"Project1"."ORG_ID" AS "ORG_ID", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID", 
"Project1"."EWM_STATION_ID" AS "EWM_STATION_ID", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID", 
"Project1"."REFERENCE_POINT_ELEVATION" AS "REFERENCE_POINT_ELEVATION", 
"Project1"."GROUND_SURFACE_ELEVATION" AS "GROUND_SURFACE_ELEVATION", 
"Project1"."WATER_SURFACE_READING" AS "WATER_SURFACE_READING", 
"Project1"."REFERENCE_POINT_READING" AS "REFERENCE_POINT_READING", 
"Project1"."MANDATORY_READING" AS "MANDATORY_READING", 
"Project1"."COMMENTS" AS "COMMENTS", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC", 
"Project1"."COOPERATING_AGENCY_ORG_ID" AS "COOPERATING_AGENCY_ORG_ID", 
"Project1"."APPL_ID" AS "APPL_ID", 
"Project1"."SUBMISSION_DATE" AS "SUBMISSION_DATE", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID1" AS "EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID1", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CODE" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CODE", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_DESC" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_DESC", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ACTV" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ACTV", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ORDER" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ORDER", 
"Project1"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CLASS" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CLASS", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_DATE1" AS "MODIFIED_DATE1", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_USER1" AS "MODIFIED_USER1", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_PROC1" AS "MODIFIED_PROC1", 
"Project1"."APPL_ID1" AS "APPL_ID1", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID1" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID1", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_DESC" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_DESC", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ACTV" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ACTV", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ORDER" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ORDER", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_DATE3" AS "MODIFIED_DATE2", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_USER3" AS "MODIFIED_USER2", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_PROC3" AS "MODIFIED_PROC2", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_CD" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_CD", 
"Project1"."APPL_ID3" AS "APPL_ID2", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID1" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID1", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_DESC" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_DESC", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ACTV" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ACTV", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ORDER" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ORDER", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_DATE2" AS "MODIFIED_DATE3", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_USER2" AS "MODIFIED_USER3", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_PROC2" AS "MODIFIED_PROC3", 
"Project1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_CD" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_CD", 
"Project1"."APPL_ID2" AS "APPL_ID3", 
"Project1"."ORG_ID1" AS "ORG_ID1", 
"Project1"."ORG_NAME" AS "ORG_NAME", 
"Project1"."ORG_ABBR" AS "ORG_ABBR", 
"Project1"."ORG_TYPE_ID" AS "ORG_TYPE_ID", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_DATE4" AS "MODIFIED_DATE4", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_USER4" AS "MODIFIED_USER4", 
"Project1"."MODIFIED_PROC4" AS "MODIFIED_PROC4", 
"Project1"."ORG_TIN" AS "ORG_TIN"
FROM ( SELECT 
"Extent1"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READ_JRL_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READ_JRL_ID", 
"Extent1"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READING_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READING_ID", 
"Extent1"."CRUD_TYPE" AS "CRUD_TYPE", 
"Extent1"."CRUD_DT" AS "CRUD_DT", 
"Extent1"."MEASUREMENT_DT" AS "MEASUREMENT_DT", 
"Extent1"."ORG_ID" AS "ORG_ID", 
"Extent1"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID", 
"Extent1"."EWM_STATION_ID" AS "EWM_STATION_ID", 
"Extent1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID", 
"Extent1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID", 
"Extent1"."REFERENCE_POINT_ELEVATION" AS "REFERENCE_POINT_ELEVATION", 
"Extent1"."GROUND_SURFACE_ELEVATION" AS "GROUND_SURFACE_ELEVATION", 
"Extent1"."WATER_SURFACE_READING" AS "WATER_SURFACE_READING", 
"Extent1"."REFERENCE_POINT_READING" AS "REFERENCE_POINT_READING", 
"Extent1"."MANDATORY_READING" AS "MANDATORY_READING", 
"Extent1"."COMMENTS" AS "COMMENTS", 
"Extent1"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE", 
"Extent1"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER", 
"Extent1"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC", 
"Extent1"."COOPERATING_AGENCY_ORG_ID" AS "COOPERATING_AGENCY_ORG_ID", 
"Extent1"."APPL_ID" AS "APPL_ID", 
"Extent1"."SUBMISSION_DATE" AS "SUBMISSION_DATE", 
1 AS "C1", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID1", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CODE" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CODE", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_DESC" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_DESC", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ACTV" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ACTV", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ORDER" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_ORDER", 
"Extent2"."EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CLASS" AS "EWM_MEASURE_ISSUE_TYPE_CLASS", 
"Extent2"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE1", 
"Extent2"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER1", 
"Extent2"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC1", 
"Extent2"."APPL_ID" AS "APPL_ID1", 
"Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID1", 
"Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_DESC" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_DESC", 
"Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ACTV" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ACTV", 
"Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ORDER" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_ORDER", 
"Extent3"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE2", 
"Extent3"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER2", 
"Extent3"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC2", 
"Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_CD" AS "EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_CD", 
"Extent3"."APPL_ID" AS "APPL_ID2", 
**"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID1"**, 
"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_DESC" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_DESC", 
"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ACTV" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ACTV", 
"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ORDER" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_ORDER", 
"Extent4"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE3", 
"Extent4"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER3", 
"Extent4"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC3", 
"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_CD" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_CD", 
"Extent4"."APPL_ID" AS "APPL_ID3", 
"Extent5"."ORG_ID" AS "ORG_ID1", 
"Extent5"."ORG_NAME" AS "ORG_NAME", 
"Extent5"."ORG_ABBR" AS "ORG_ABBR", 
"Extent5"."ORG_TYPE_ID" AS "ORG_TYPE_ID", 
"Extent5"."MODIFIED_DATE" AS "MODIFIED_DATE4", 
"Extent5"."MODIFIED_USER" AS "MODIFIED_USER4", 
"Extent5"."MODIFIED_PROC" AS "MODIFIED_PROC4", 
"Extent5"."ORG_TIN" AS "ORG_TIN"
FROM     "EWM_ADM"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READING_JRL" "Extent1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "EWM_ADM"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID" = "Extent2"."EWM_MEASUREMENT_ISSUE_TYPE_ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "EWM_ADM"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP" "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID" = "Extent3"."EWM_ELEV_MEASURE_METHOD_TYP_ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "EWM_ADM"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE" "Extent4" ON "Extent1"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID" = "Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "BUS_ADM"."ORGANIZATION" "Extent5" ON "Extent1"."COOPERATING_AGENCY_ORG_ID" = "Extent5"."ORG_ID"
WHERE (("Extent1"."EWM_STATION_ID" = 52370) OR (("Extent1"."EWM_STATION_ID" IS NULL) AND (52370 IS NULL)))
)  "Project1"
ORDER BY "Project1"."EWM_ELEVATION_DATA_READ_JRL_ID" DESC
```

The line in question is this one (marked with asterisks in the query since I cannot bold it).

```
"Extent4"."EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID" AS "EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID1"
```

As you can see it appended a 1 to the alias. I need to prevent that or force a custom alias name.

Comment: BTW my model is mapped to the column name by this, there is no other code in the dbContext for this column.

[Column("EWM_ELEVATION_ACCURACY_TYPE_ID")]
public long? ElevationAccuracyTypeId { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's old question but maybe will be actual for somebody who has to use old EF and Oracle 12c. But here is solution which is working fine for me:

1. Create a new Interceptor with the following code:

```
    public class InterceptorFixAliasesLength : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            FixNameLength(command);
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            FixNameLength(command);
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        private static void FixNameLength(DbCommand command)
        {
            var text = command.CommandText;
            // Looking something like "AS "PARAMETER_1"" where PARAMETER_1 is the parameter name and length is greater than 30 characters
            var pattern = @"AS ""([A-Z0-9_]{31,})""";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

            var anyUpdated = false;
            foreach(Match m in matches)
            {
                // if the alias is longer than 30 characters, generate a new unique alias
                var paramName = m.Groups[1].Value;
                if (paramName.Length > 30)
                {
                    var newParamName = paramName.Substring(0, 27);
                    var newParamNameUnique = newParamName;
                    var i = 1;
                    while (text.Contains(newParamNameUnique))
                    {
                        newParamNameUnique = $"{newParamName}_{i}";
                        i++;
                    }
                    text = text.Replace($"\"{paramName}\"", $"\"{newParamNameUnique}\"");
                    anyUpdated = true;
                }
            }

            if (anyUpdated)
            {
                command.CommandText = text;
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Add this Interceptor to your DbConfiguration:

```
    public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyDbConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(new InterceptorFixAliasesLength());
        }
    }
```

3. Now all commands (only for select requests) will be checked and fixed before execution